# Windows Server 2008: Setting up VPN in a VPS

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

I have an instance of Windows Server 2008 (without Hyper-V) running on a Rackspace virtual server. I am trying to get VPN configured on it, so that I can securely connect to my Database with SQL Server Management studio.

When I configure the Routing and Remote Access server role, my web server is inaccessible on the Internet (my site goes down), and I can't even access the server via RDP. It appears that maybe Rackspace has some enhanced security settings that are causing this.

Here're the steps that I'm following:

1. Selecting Remote Access (dial-up or VPN)
2. Selecting the public interface (with the server IP address that is accessible on the Internet)
3. Automatic IP address allocation (I am doing this because I don't know which IP addresses I can statically assign)
4. Do not use RADIUS

When I click Finish, I get the message "To support relaying of DHCP messages, you must configure the DHCP remote client". After this, my web server becomes inaccessible. In the remote access network policies, I have two policies. Both are on Deny by default. I have tried setting "Connections to Microsoft Routing and Remote Access Server" to Grant Access, but this doesn't help. The server remains inaccessible. I can connect via VPN, but that's of little help.

Can anybody help me figure out what configuration settings are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had checked the option "Enable security on the selected interface by setting up static packet filters." This meant that connections were *only* allowed through the VPN, which is why I was unable to connect to the server via FTP/RDP. I reconfigured the VPN without this option, and it works as intended.